# Share a simple text file between 2 linux instance in gcp

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, scp

I have two linux instances in gcp and both are in the same project i created a demo.txt file in instance-1 and i want to transfer this file from instance-1 to instance-2, so i came up with this command

`scp -i ~/.ssh/my-ssh-key [USERNAME]@[IP_ADDRESS]:[REMOTE_FILE_PATH] [LOCAL_FILE_PATH]`

i also created a key using this command in instance-1

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/[ssh-key] -C [root]`

my ssh-key is located in `/root/.ssh` it have two file '[ssh-key]' and '[ssh-key].pub' and i use exactly this command to share file

`scp -i ~/.ssh/'[ssh-key].pub' [root]@[externalIP_of_instance-2]:/usr/ /usr/demo.txt`

but getting this error.

`external_ip_of_instance-2: Permission denied (publickey)`

what am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your `[ssh-key].pub` key of the machine you are connecting from to authorized keys on machine you are connecting to.
The location of this file is:

```
~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```